# Custom font is changed in browser

Tags: css, fonts

After a long search for the right font, I decided to create my own. I based it off a photoshop Arial font that was alised (pixelated = anti-aliassed:none).

Here is the photoshop rendition of the font

[image: anti-aliassed:none font from photshop]

After, I created a font using FontStruct with the exact same pixel configuration it would show up in photoshop with each individual letter. I created the font, tested it in photoshop and it worked beautifully in photoshop. It would appear exactly the same. BUT then I added it to my website to be used and for some reason the browser shrunk the font horizontally.

[image: website font rendition]

Why did it shrink horizontally? My font size is 8px and at 8px it should show perfectly, but instead is is horizontally squeezed. Any thoughts? Thanks

The font is linked with css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Arial Pixel';
  src: url('ArialPixel.ttf');
}
```

and it is shown through h1 tag

```
h1 {
    text-align    : center; 
    color         : #FFF;
    font          : 8px 'Arial Pixel'; }
```

[Font is here](http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/1097915)

Comment: The image shows the result of anti-aliasing (font smoothing) in addition to the shrinking effect. This depends on the browser, and you should identify the browser(s) tested. The shrinking may be connected with anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll need to convert the .ttf file here http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
2. From here you'll need to upload the font files (referenced below) to your server. Absolute URLs won't work with web fonts so keep it local
3. Use the following code

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arial_pixelregular';
    src: url('arialpixel-webfont.eot');
    src: url('arialpixel-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('arialpixel-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('arialpixel-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('arialpixel-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('arialpixel-webfont.svg#arial_pixelregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'arial_pixelregular';
    font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>ABC</h1>
```

Comment: The font is taken from a .ttf file that I created and linked within my CSS.

Comment: I added a link to the font file above. Photoshop 8px with the .ttf shows the font perfectly yet online it creates shadows and shrinks the font. CAPITAL letters only.